# converting PointCloud2 to pcl::PointCloud is slow with RGB field

Tags: ros, pcl, pcl-conversions

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I measured a time to convert `sensor_msgs::PointCloud2`, `pcl::PointCloud` and `pcl::PCLPointCloud2`.
https://github.com/garaemon/pcl_ros_conversion_benchmark

I found that converting from `pcl::PCLPointCloud2` to `pcl::PointCloud` takes a long time when the input data had RGB field.
Is there any way to speed up this conversion?

[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/167506/converting-pointcloud2-to-pcl::pointcloud-is-slow-with-rgb-field/) by [Ryohei Ueda](https://answers.ros.org/users/59/ryohei-ueda/) on ROS Answers with karma: 317 on 2014-05-20

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My best guess is that when transforming from PCL2 to PCL you need to get rid of the RGB field.

If I am not mistaken, the representation in memory of the point cloud for PCL2 is something like:

```
[X0, Y0, Z0, RGB0, X1, Y1, Z1, RGB1, ... Xn, Yn, Zn, RGBn]
```

and for PCL is:

```
[X0, Y0, Z0, X1, Y1, Z1, ... Xn, Yn, Zn]
```

So the only way to transform from PCL2 to PCL is by iterating over the data on PCL2 and ignoring each 4th component (the RGB component) and this takes time, because you can not do a simple memcpy.

Inside the implementation of [fromPCLPointCloud2](http://docs.pointclouds.org/1.7.0/conversions_8h_source.html#l00167) between lines 202 and 217 you will see what I mean.

---

Originally posted by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) with karma: 5625 on 2014-05-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ryohei Ueda](https://answers.ros.org/users/59/ryohei-ueda/) on 2014-05-21**:
Thanks! you are correct.
When I use `pcl::PointXYZRGBA`, the conversion time decreases.